# Ocaml Tree simple functions

Tags: tree, ocaml

I created a tree

```
type 'a tree = {
      mutable cont: 'a;
      mutable left: 'a bin_tree;
      mutable right: 'a bin_tree
}
and 'a bin_tree =
     Empty
     | Node of 'a tree;;
```

and I'm struggling to do with some simple functions like

- insertion of elements (to the propper subtrees, no duplicates)
- making union of two binary trees

I googled my problem but I'm constantly getting errors. For example:

```
let rec insert x tree =
match tree with
 Empty -> Node(x, Empty, Empty)
| Node(y, left, right) ->
   if x <= y then Node(y, insert x left, right)
             else Node(y, left, insert x right)
```

or if I try:

```
let rec insert x = function
Empty -> Node(Empty, x, Empty)
| Node(lb, r, rb) -> if x < r then Node(insert x lb, r, rb)
else Node{lb; r; insert x rb} ;;
```

I'm constantly getting Syntax Error.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you use a mutable record for your tree? OCaml programmers prefer to use immutable data structures. Here the mutability of your tree doesn't improve the complexity but can introduce bugs.

Here is how to implement trees in a persistent way:

```
type 'a tree =
| Empty
| Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
```

and it is actually this type that you use in your code for `member` and `insert`.

Comment: I'm preparing for exam and this is one of the problems we got as a preparation to test. I don't know why they choose to make mutable data.

Comment: I have to say it doesn't look like idiomatic OCaml code to me. The type seems too complicated for what it does, and the mutability is suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Your match pattern should contain `{` and `}` to match a record so code

```
match tree with
   Empty -> false
  | Node { cont=x; left=l; right=r } -> (*something here .... *)
```

Actually, a [language extension for record notation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#toc78) permit to avoid the field labels when the pattern variable has the same name as the field, so instead of coding a pattern `Node { cont=cont; left=left; right=right }` you can code `Node{cont;left;right}`

You could also look into Ocaml's [stdlib/set.ml](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/trunk/stdlib/set.ml?view=markup) source file.

Notice that your `'a bin_tree` type is nearly equivalent to `'a tree option`.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to do insert:

`let rec insert x tree =
   match tree with
     Empty -> Node{x; Empty; Empty}
   | Node{cont; left; right} ->
       if x <= y then Node {y; insert x left; right}
                 else Node {y; left; insert x right};;`

I don't think that's right though

Comment: At least it probably compiles. I cannot tell if it is what your teacher expects. He may want you to keep the trees somehow balanced...

Comment: Trees should be balanced properly, yes. Left subtree contains elements that are smaller than the node, and the right those that are bigger. And there should be no duplicates.

Comment: (That's not balancing, that's ordering. Balancing is something that keeps the *height* of the tree roughly equal to the log of the number of nodes.)

Comment: Well no instructions regarding that then.