# Add elements in 'a tree in Ocaml

Tags: tree, ocaml, binary-tree

So, here is my problem..
I need to write a function that will add elements in a tree and it is a binary tree, so it must be well organized. The problem is in how is my tree defined.
I have this tree:

```
type 'a tree = {
  mutable cont:'a;
  mutable left:'a bin_tree;
  mutable right:'a bin_tree
  }
  and 'a bin_tree = 
  Empty
  |Node of 'a bin_tree;;
```

So, when I write the function to add elements in this tree it says that the tree is of type 'a tree and I am using function for 'a bin_tree.

I tried a lot of different ways to write that function and I get the same error.
The function I used last is:

```
let rec dodajVDrevo x = function
Empty -> Node{cont=x; left=Empty; right=Empty}
|Node{cont; left; right} -> if x < cont then Node{cont; left= dodajVDrevo x left; right}
else if x > cont then Node{cont; left; right = dodajVDrevo x right}
else Node{cont; left; right};;
```

Please help me and give some clues.

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you define left, right and cont as mutable? Your add function (dodajVDrevo) is already pure.
Since it looks like homework, I assume that the sense of your exercise to get familar with a functional programming style; not dirty c-like ocaml code with mutability.

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507273/ocaml-tree-simple-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Node` constructor should take a `'a tree` instead of a `'a bin_tree`.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean? Just replace the text `|Node of 'a bin_tree` with `|Node of 'a tree`.